# Ethernet.h Ethernet.Begin(mac) only connects if i have a LiquidCrystal object from LiquidCrystal.H

Tags: lcd, ethernet, ethernet-shield

I have the following code;

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22);
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //client.begin(mac);
  //Init Ethernet Comms
  Serial.println(F("Start."));
  while (!Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Network Error"));
    delay(200);
  };
  Serial.println(F("Connected"));

}

void loop() {}
```

As it is above it gets out of the while loop. However, if i remove the line `LiquidCrystal lcd(31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22);`It will then fail to connect, and stay in the loop. Im at a complete loss here as the Ethernet shield and 2x16 LCD are unrelated devices, and if anything id expect the addition of used pins to cause issue, not the removal.

Edit: I should note this is occurring on two devices, one Mega one Uno.

2nd Edit: As pointed out by Juraj in the comments, this can be resolved using Ethernet.Init(CS_Pin) where CS_Pin is an unused pin, in my case D9.

Comment: do you have SD card inserted? if yes remove it or set the SD CS pin 4 HIGH. And I would add `Ethernet.init(10);`. What happens if you disconnect the LCD?

Comment: You beauty, that was exactly the issue. Oddly i have been using both the SD card and Ethernet port without issue for a while now, but only recently ran into this issue.